# triggering dblclick in google map when an overlay exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

i have a problem triggering the_map dblclick event when i have a circle overlay on it.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(the_map, 'dblclick',  function(myEvent) { 
    // do something
}
```

i have add the below code to the circle.polygon object but it doesnt work.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.polygon, 'dblclick', function(myEvent) {
    $(this.map).trigger('dblclick', myEvent)
    // or
    $(this.map).dblclick(myEvent)
})
```

can any one help? or describe why it doesnt work?

Comment: I haven't used the Google Map API much and not in the mood to setup an example but I can help if you provide a jsFiddle example of the problem I can diagnose it.  The first questions that pops in my head is does the `dblclick` event on your polygon even get fired when you double click it (do an alert)?  The second is if it doesn't then check if the single `click` event does.  If so you can then use that to make a mock dblclick event by counting the number of times the user clicks and if it's whiten a certain time span they click twice then call the dblclick event of the map.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this post when looking for the same answer. I couldn't find one so I am adding my solution for posterity.

The following is a self installing class which executes double and single clicks regardless of whether or not an overlay is present on the maps.

```
map_click._single(function(event){        
    console.log(event);        
});
```

Is equivalent to:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {        
    console.log(event);
});
```

And for double clicks...

```
map_click._double(function(event){        
    console.log(event);        
});
```

Is equivalent to:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(event) {        
    console.log(event);
});
```

If you want to set the double click delay you can edit it like:

```
map_click.delay = 300;
```

The default is 300ms which is what I found works best. You could effectively remove double click events by setting `map_click.delay` to 0.

FInally the function:

```
window.map_click = {
    i : 0
    ,_single : function(fn){
        if(typeof(fn) != 'function') return;
        this.singles = this.singles || [];
        this.singles.push(fn);
    }
    ,_double : function(fn){
        if(typeof(fn) != 'function') return;
        this.doubles = this.doubles || [];
        this.doubles.push(fn);
    }
    ,delay : 300
    ,_ : (function(){
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(event) {
            if(map_click.timeout) clearTimeout(map_click.timeout);
            map_click.i = 0;
            for(_ in map_click.doubles)
                map_click.doubles[_](event);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            map_click.i++;
            map_click._event = event;
            if(map_click.timeout) clearTimeout(map_click.timeout);
            if(!(map_click.i%2)){
                map_click.i = 0;
                for(_ in map_click.doubles)
                    map_click.doubles[_](event);    
            }else{
                map_click.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    map_click.i = 0;
                    for(_ in map_click.singles)
                        map_click.singles[_](map_click._event);
                }, map_click.delay);
            }

        });
    })()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Map API for the [dblclick](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.dblclick) event:

> This event is fired when a double click is done on the map. **Notice
> that this event will not be fired if the double click was on a marker
> or other clickable overlay.** The geographical coordinates of the point
> that was double clicked are passed in the latlng argument. The overlay
> argument is always set to null.

---

**Note:**
That link and summary above was for the v2 documentation but the same applies to v3 [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html); if you scroll down to the `dblclick` event:

> click           MouseEvent      This event is fired when the user clicks on the map
> (**but not when they click on a marker or infowindow**).
>
> dblclick      MouseEvent      This event is fired when the user double-clicks on
> the map. **Note that the click event will also fire, right before this
> one.**

Comment: -1 i can read the toturials. you`re not answering my question

Comment: sorry @jeffwilbert, i aggree with wtayyeb, this answer doesnt answer much at all.  it might even end up downvoted by some zealous user.

Answer (score 0):

Just set circle **clickable** option to false.

[Google Maps V3 - Circle Options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CircleOptions)